# fragment not work and have errors

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

have app get image and text from server then show that in card view 
[image]
and have another app with different tabs and which tab extend from Fragment 
[image]

so want put my first app in which one of second app tabs .
like this : 
[image]

so paste my main activity code from first app in fragment but have errors :

```
public class news extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ArrayList<Deatails> data;
    private DataAdapter adapter;


    private View myFragmentView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    myFragmentView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.news, container, false);
      initViews();
    return myFragmentView;
}

    private void initViews() {

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        loadJSON();
    }

    private void loadJSON() {

            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://memaraneha.ir/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            RequestInterface request = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
            Call<JSONResponse> call = request.getJSON();

            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progressDialog.show();

            call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
                    data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getAndroid()));
                    adapter = new DataAdapter(MainActivity.this, data);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
                }
            });
    }
}
```

this is my errors :

[image]

,,,,

[image]

,,,,

[image]

Comment: Show your Activity code too please

Comment: i add main activity . but main activity not have errors

Comment: Have you ever used fragments? Have you tried to check any tutorial of fragments which shows how you can inflate layouts and initialize views?

Comment: all examples just show 1button in fragment . not so many codes ...can u help me ?

Comment: Activity is ok, you should show news layout also in xml

Comment: just have Recycler View  inside news xml with id :card_recycler_view

Comment: You should have inflater.inflate(R.layout.news, container, false); in your OnCreateView method, no? And depends on your code card_recycler_view is placed inside your fragment`s  layout

Comment: if u want help me and i give you vote. just edit ur answer and tell me where i must change my code or put where ur codes .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve my problems so its correct code for people :

```
public class news extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ArrayList<Deatails> data;
    private DataAdapter adapter;
    private View myFragmentView;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        myFragmentView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.news, container, false);
        initViews();
        return myFragmentView;
    }

    private void initViews() {

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        loadJSON();
    }

    private void loadJSON() {

            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://memaraneha.ir/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            RequestInterface request = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
            Call<JSONResponse> call = request.getJSON();

            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progressDialog.show();

            call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
                    data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getAndroid()));
                    adapter = new DataAdapter(getActivity(), data);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use link to `View` inside your `Fragment`.

**Inside Fragment**

```
private View myFragmentView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news, container, false);
    return myFragmentView;
}
```

You cannot just copy paste code from your activity to your fragment.
You need to launch findViewById from your fragment view.

```
myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.addYourViewHere);
```

You cannot run init methods before `OnCreateView` method of your fragment.

Comment: i edit my code lookat . that true ? so my 3 errors solve but that 3 error still had in my code

Comment: @erfan Do you have R.id.card_recycler_view in R.layout.news? Where do you have errors?

Answer (score 1):

When you are using fragment, u have to override it's `onCreateView` method.

Example:

```
public class FavFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorite, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    layoutEmpty = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.layoutEmpty);
    btnShowOnMap = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btnShowOnMap);
    fabRoulette = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fabRoulette);
    mainView = v.findViewById(R.id.mainView);


    return v;
}
```

Comment: i edit my code lookat . that true ? so my 3 errors solve but that 3 error still had in my code

Comment: please, give some more information about these 3 errors.